# How to properly set/read a cookie in js-cookie library?

Tags: javascript, cookies, js-cookie

I just recently started trying to use the cookie library js-cookie:

Found here: https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

I can't seem to determine whether my cookies are being set or read correctly. The main goal is to read if a checkbox is checked, create a cookie and use that on another page to change some elements.

Here's how I attempted setting the cookie:

```
$('#food').click(function() {
   if ($(this).is(':checked')){
      Cookies.set('food', 'true');
   }
   else{
      Cookies.remove('food');
   }
});
```

It properly reads the checkbox being checked on click, so I know it is at least reaching the cookie set.

For reading the cookie value:

```
if(Cookies.get('food') === 'true'){
   $('#food').css("color", "#198a80");
}
```

I followed the documentation on the repository page for setting and it looks correct. I assumed reading the cookie just passed the value portion as a normal variable and it could be compared like normal, but the code just does nothing, so I guessed the problem was either with the setting or reading of the cookie.

Comment: Developer Tools -> Storage -> Cookies

Comment: [How can I debug my JavaScript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code)

Comment: Thanks. I did find the cookie section in the dev tools. Now I know that the cookies aren't actually being set to begin with. Unfortunately, I'm not the most familiar with the js-cookie library at the moment, so that's as far as I can get in diagnosing the issue with why the code isn't working. I followed their example code pretty close so I'm out of ideas.